# SonarQube create a dynamical dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, dashboard, sonarqube-web

I want to know if somebody know if it possible to create a dynamical dashboard. By dynamical, I want to say, a dashboard that displays the different widgets depending on the results that have changed from the previous execution .
For example, if the lines of source code comments have greatly diminished , it result appears first in the dashboard. The user can see the detail in first.

Thank you If you know help because I don't find an issue at it problem.

Thank you

Comment: You've just described exactly what dashboards do.

Comment: No, I created a dashboard with different widgets. 
The widget displays different things and I want to know if it is possible for example to change the position of the different widgets if one widget has more critical errors than another one.
If it is possible to dynamically put the widget with more errors at the beginning of the dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, widgets are not positioned dynamically.